# is there a way to use your current credentials to assume a service account instead of having to use the json key?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud, google-iam

My personal account is an admin in my gcp project.

If I want to use one of the service accounts I have created (from my local laptop) I do this:

```
gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file=some-service-account.json
```

But I wonder, if I already have my own admin account active, is there a way to just assume a service account without the key? Can GCP use my current creds to give me access to assume that service account?

If so this also makes me wonder if I can use service accounts applied to GCE instances the same way. So I can attach a service account to a GCE instance that gives it access to assume *other* service accounts.

Comment: Service Account Impersonation: https://www.jhanley.com/google-cloud-improving-security-with-impersonation/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is "impersonation". You need roles like `iam.serviceAccountUser` to do this. Refer to these docs and articles:

- https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/service-accounts#the_service_account_user_role
- https://medium.com/google-cloud/using-serviceaccountactor-iam-role-for-account-impersonation-on-google-cloud-platform-a9e7118480ed
- https://medium.com/google-cloud/impersonating-users-with-google-cloud-platform-service-accounts-ba762db09092

Comment: Is it possible to impersonate a service account with gcloud running locally without using a json key generated for the service account?

Answer (score 0):

The Google Cloud documentation does not make it exactly obvious how to do this. I scoured many disparate online resource and was able to get NodeJS to do Service Account impersonation using my Google Account ADC, **without having to manage service account keys** using the following setup:

1. *optional*: destroy your `~/.config/gcloud` directory to ensure no other pre-existing login credentials conflict with the authentication: `rm -rf ~/.config/gcloud`
2. provide ADC to gcloud: `gcloud auth application-default login` and follow the login flow in the browser, logging in with your Google Account.
3. provide your ADC Google Account the **Service Account Token Creator** Role on the Service Account you are trying to impersonate.
4. The IAM Service Account Credentials API must be enable in your GCP Project. I thought this was the same as the IAM API. It is not. Goto **GCP** -> **APIs & Services** -> **Enable APIs & Services** -> search for it, and Enable it.
5. install the necessary dependencies, and run the code below (example uses BigQuery):

```js
const { BigQuery }                 = require('@google-cloud/bigquery');
const { GoogleAuth, Impersonated } = require('google-auth-library');

const projectId           = 'your-project';
const serviceAccountEmail = `your-sa@${projectId}.iam.gserviceaccount.com`;
const scopes              = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform'];
const delegates           = [];
const lifetime            = 3600;

(async () => {

  const auth         = new GoogleAuth({ scopes });
  const sourceClient = await auth.getClient();

  const authClient = new Impersonated({
      sourceClient,
      targetPrincipal: serviceAccountEmail,
      lifetime,
      delegates,
      targetScopes: scopes
  });

  const bigquery = new BigQuery({ projectId, authClient });

  const response = await bigquery.query('select 1 as x ');
  
  /* should print [ [ { x: 1 } ] ] */
  console.log(response);
  
})()
```